# multiple tween on single node kinetic.js

Tags: position, kineticjs, tween

I have a bar diagram for a polling system.i want two transition(tween) effects on events they are following

1. Mouse over OR check box check
2. Click button

I am using the same node for tween.tween.play() is working fine but on reverse the y cordinate that i gave in tween constructor not working.

checkout my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shyamjptpm/ynNUN/)

---

```
var stagewidthbywindow = 1000;  
var stagesetting = {  
    container: "container_1_1_0",  
    width: stagewidthbywindow,  
    height: 50  
};  

var rectwidth0 = 0;  
var rectSum = 0;  
var stage110 = new Kinetic.Stage(stagesetting);  
var layer110 = new Kinetic.Layer();  
var group110 = new Kinetic.Group();  
layer110.add(group110);   

function increasestage() {  
    var myChecker = setInterval(function () {  
        var stage_height = stage110.getHeight();  
        if (stage_height == 250) {  
            clearInterval(myChecker);  
        } else {  

            stage110.setAttr("height", stage_height + 2.5);
        }
    }, 10);
}
var rectwidth1 = stagesetting.width * 0.5;
rectSum += rectwidth0;
var rectObject1 = {
    x: rectSum,
    y: 0,
    width: rectwidth1,
    height: 50,
    fill: "#DA4B4B",
    stroke: "#ffffff",
    strokeWidth: 2,
    opacity: 1
};

var shadeObject = {
    x: rectSum,
    y: 0,
    width: stagewidthbywindow,
    height: 50,
    fill: "#f3f3f3",
    stroke: "#f3f3f3",
    strokeWidth: 1,
    opacity: 1
};
var shade111 = new Kinetic.Rect(shadeObject);
var rect111 = new Kinetic.Rect(rectObject1);


rectSum += rectwidth1;


var ansOption111 = new Kinetic.Text({
    x: rect111.getX() + 10,
    y: rect111.getY() + 10,
    text: "iPhone 5s",
    fontSize: 14,
    fontFamily: "Merriweather Sans",
    width: rect111.getWidth(),

    align: "left",
    fill: "#ffffff"
});
var ansPercentage111 = new Kinetic.Text({
    x: rect111.getX() + 10,
    y: 30,
    text: "50%",
    fontSize: 15,
    fontFamily: "Merriweather Sans",
    width: rect111.getWidth(),
    fontStyle: "bold",
    align: "left",
    fill: "#ffffff"
});

group110.add(shade111);
group110.add(rect111);

group110.add(ansOption111);
group110.add(ansPercentage111);

rect111.tween = new Kinetic.Tween({
    node: rect111,
    scaleX: 1,
    scaleY: 5,
    easing: Kinetic.Easings.Linear,
    duration: .5
});
ansOption111.tween = new Kinetic.Tween({
    node: ansOption111,
    scaleX: 1.5,
    scaleY: 1.5,
    x: rect111.getX() + 20,
    y: 20,
    easing: Kinetic.Easings.Linear,
    duration: .5,

});
ansPercentage111.tween = new Kinetic.Tween({
    node: ansPercentage111,
    x: rect111.getX() + 20,
    y: 100,
    scaleX: 3,
    scaleY: 3,
    easing: Kinetic.Easings.Linear,
    duration: .5,

});
rect111.on("mouseover touchstart", function (evt) {
    if (!$("#sample_size1").is(":checked") &&
        $("#orientation_1_1_0").val() == "horizontal") {
        stage110.setAttr("height", 250);
        rect111.tween.play();
        ansOption111.tween.play();
        ansPercentage111.tween.play();
    }
});
rect111.on("mouseout touchend", function (evt) {
    if (!$("#sample_size1").is(":checked") &&
        $("#orientation_1_1_0").val() == "horizontal") {
        stage110.setAttr("height", 50);
        rect111.tween.reverse();
        ansOption111.tween.reverse();
        ansPercentage111.tween.reverse();
    }
});
ansOption111.on("mouseover touchstart", function (evt) {
    if (!$("#sample_size1").is(":checked") &&
        $("#orientation_1_1_0").val() == "horizontal") {
        stage110.setAttr("height", 250);
        rect111.tween.play();
        ansOption111.tween.play();
        ansPercentage111.tween.play();
    }
});
ansOption111.on("mouseout touchend", function (evt) {
    if (!$("#sample_size1").is(":checked") &&
        $("#orientation_1_1_0").val() == "horizontal") {
        stage110.setAttr("height", 50);
        rect111.tween.reverse();
        ansOption111.tween.reverse();
        ansPercentage111.tween.reverse();
    }
});
$("#sample_size1").change(function () {
    if ($(this).is(":checked") && $("#orientation_1_1_0").val() == "horizontal") {
        var scaleFactor = 5;
        increasestage();
        stage110.draw();
        rect111.tween.play();
        ansOption111.tween.play();
        ansPercentage111.tween.play();

    } else if (!$(this).is(":checked") && $("#orientation_1_1_0").val() == "horizontal") {
        rect111.tween.reverse();
        ansOption111.tween.reverse();
        ansPercentage111.tween.reverse();
        setTimeout(function () {
            stage110.setAttr("height", 50);
        }, 600);
    }
});
var rectangle111 = new Kinetic.Tween({
    node: rect111,
    duration: .5,
    x: 0,
    y: 20 * 1 + 18 * 0,
    width: rectwidth1,
    height: 20,
    opacity: 1,
    scaleX: 1
    //scaleY: 0.4
});
var shadetween111 = new Kinetic.Tween({
    node: shade111,
    duration: .5,
    x: 0,
    y: 20 * 1 + 18 * 0,
    //width: stagewidthbywindow,
    height: 20,
    opacity: 1,
    scaleX: 1

});

var answerOption111 = new Kinetic.Tween({
    node: ansOption111,
    duration: .5,
    x: 0,
    y: (40 * 0),
    width: 150,
    height: 15,
    opacity: .9,
    strokeWidth: 2,
    scaleX: 1

});


function call_answerPercentage111() {
    var answerPercentage111 = new Kinetic.Tween({
        node: ansPercentage111,
        x: 160,
        y: (40 * 0),
        width: 150,
        height: 18,
        opacity: .9,
        duration: 0.5,

        strokeWidth: 2,
        scaleX: 1


    });
    return answerPercentage111;
}

document.getElementById("arrow110").addEventListener("click", function () {

    if ($("#orientation_1_1_0").val() == "horizontal") {
        $("#arrow110").addClass("btn-arow-down");
        stage110.setAttr("height", 4 * 40);
        $("#orientation_1_1_0").val("vertical");
        if ($("#sample_size1").is(":checked")) {
            console.log("destroy");
        }
        ansPercentage111.setFill("black");
        ansOption111.setFill("black");
        rectangle111.play();
        shadetween111.play();
        answerOption111.play();
        var answerPercentage111 = call_answerPercentage111();
        answerPercentage111.play();
        layer110.draw();
    } else if ($("#orientation_1_1_0").val() == "vertical") {
        $("#arrow110").removeClass("btn-arow-down");
        $("#orientation_1_1_0").val("horizontal");
        ansPercentage111.setFill("white");
        ansOption111.setFill("white");
        rectangle111.reverse();
        shadetween111.reverse();
        answerOption111.reverse();
        var answerPercentage111 = call_answerPercentage111();
        answerPercentage111.reverse();
        answerPercentage111.destroy();
        layer110.draw();
        setTimeout(function () {
            stage110.setAttr("height", 50);
        }, 1000);
    }
}, false);
stage110.add(layer110);
```

Answer (score 0):

On calling `call_answerPercentage111` you are creating new tween. You can not reverse tween that is not played with `play()` function.   Also you are calling `destroy()` method after `reverse()` - you can do this ONLY after tween is done (or you will stop the tween).

http://jsfiddle.net/ynNUN/3/

Comment: Thank you Iavarton,but i called that function because i want to show the 50% text on the bottom of rectangle as it comes in first time mouseover event.After calling answerPercentage111 function the y value of of answerPercentage111 is set to 0 it is not setting to 100 again on second mouseover on the rect111 please check my jsfiddle once again.Thanks you in advance